# User info from VKontakte in Android

Tags: android, vk

I am writing an application that needs to use the user data taken from the client social network VKontakte.
I did authorize VKontakte.

```
VKSdk.initialize(sdkListener, String.valueOf(idVK), VKAccessToken.tokenFromSharedPreferences(this, sTokenKey));
```

And got AccessToken.
As now I get the name and email user?

Comment: don't know about the name, but I guess you might not get email if the user did not make it public

Answer (score 8):

You can request email scope from user, then get email from access token:

```
String email = VKSdk.getAccessToken().email;
String userId = VKSdk.getAccessToken().userId;

//Get user info
VKApi.users().get().executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        VKApiUser user = ((VKList<VKApiUser>)response.parsedModel).get(0);
        Log.d("User name", user.first_name + " " + user.last_name);
    }
});
```

But remember, email is only available after first access request.

***Old answer:***

<s>You can't get an email. This is not available. But you can get user name:</s>

```
VKApi.users().get().executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        VKApiUser user = ((VKList<VKApiUser>)response.parsedModel).get(0);
        Log.d("User name", user.first_name + " " + user.last_name);
    }
});
```

Comment: Also you shouldn't forget to add `VKScope.EMAIL` into `VKSdk.login(context, VKScope.EMAIL)`

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev if only you required it.

Comment: VKSdk.getAccessToken() is now deprecated, use VKAccessToken.currentToken() instead.

Answer (score 0):

For now, you can't get user email.

But you can get other simple info from user profile via class

```
java.lang.Object
    com.vk.sdk.VKObject
        com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKApiModel
```

Here is all available info:
http://vkcom.github.io/vk-android-sdk/com/vk/sdk/api/model/VKUser.html

Answer (score 0):

After login user 
I use this code

```
 final VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_200, contacts"));
        request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                VKApiUserFull user = ((VKList<VKApiUserFull>)response.parsedModel).get(0);
                NavigationHelper.replaceFragment(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), FrHome.newInstance(String.format("%s %s,", user.first_name, user.last_name), user.mobile_phone, user.photo_200), false);
            }
        });
```

List fields you can found here
https://vk.com/dev/users.get